# Does fps relate to still photography or videography?

Tags: terminology, framerate

As a beginner, how much importance should I give to the FPS feature of a camera? How is the price of a DSLR related to the FPS? Directly or inversely? I was under the naive impression that FPS was a term related to motion pictures... i.e., the rate at which you capture or playback a set of images.

How does fps relate (if at all ) to still photography?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different meanings of FPS.  Yes, FPS is a measure of frame speed for video, but it is also a measure of the burst speed of a camera.  Video frame rates are typically 24, 25, 29.97, 30, 60, 120, 240 or 480.

The FPS that is generally referenced when talking about still cameras is not the same.  It is the  number of full pictures that the camera can take per second.  While a DSLR may be able to shoot 60fps video, it is only capturing around a 1 to 2 megapixel image when doing that, which is far less than the resolution of image the sensor can produce.  The problem is that it takes time to move data from the sensor to the processor in the camera.  So a camera that can shoot 24 fps video may only be able to shoot 8 fps of full 18MP images.  Additionally, it can generally only shoot a certain number at a time (often somewhere between 7 and 50 total images depending on resolution and quality that is used.  Do note that this can only be sustained for a short time though since once the fast cache in the camera fills, it takes more time to move the images to the memory card after processing.  This is why burst can only be used for a short time before you have to wait for it to empty.

It doesn't have any direct relationship to the price of the camera as it is also dependent on the sensor resolution and different models may give it different priority.  It might, for example, be possible to find a 12MP camera with 10 fps and the ability to shoot 19 full quality images at a time for less than the cost of a 22MP camera with the ability to shoot 8 fps and only store 17 full quality images at a time, but if you think about it, that actually makes sense since the 22MP images are much bigger than the 12MP images, so while the FPS may be lower, the 8FPS camera is actually moving more data.

Comment: The data bottleneck isn't between the sensor and the processor. It is between the memory buffer and the memory card (or the bus that connects the two).

Comment: @MichaelClark so does that mean that the processor itself is the bottleneck?

Comment: In terms of burst rate until the buffer is full - yes. The processor is also the determining factor in terms of maximum resolution/frame rate when shooting video assuming the memory buffer/memory card can keep up with it.

Comment: Video is more processor intensive due to the way video is compressed. Stills are usually more memory buffer-->card intensive due to the larger amounts of data per frame, especially when saving RAW files.

Comment: The initial burst speed is more limited by the quality of the mechanical components (the mirror flapping with DSLRs) and maybe exposure time (and marketing considerations).

Comment: @MichaelClark - the memory card has nothing to do with the bottleneck that limits the FPS rate, just the cap.  Yes, technically it is the sensor read time that is the primary problem for FPS rate, but I simplified a bit to simply say it was the time moving from the sensor to the processor to be less confusing (particularly since it is generally going from sensor to cache to processor, but then I might confuse them about memory vs cache.)

Comment: @ths - if this was true, then every camera should be able to capture dozens of frames per second when using LiveView and an electronic shutter, but they don't.  If you look at thinks like Magic Lantern which lets you bypass the limitations of mirror speed and marketing, you will see that the capture rate is directly dependent on the data read speed of the sensor.

Comment: i don't see that, ml uses hacks which probably do not reach the full potential of the hardware. anyway, there are 3fps and 12 fps cameras out there, do you want to say the 12fps camera has a 4 times faster sensor readout?

Comment: @ths - At levels like 3 frames per second, you are probably right about it being artificially limited, but at the high end, it is much more read speed limited, otherwise why would Canon give a cheap APS-C camera a faster burst speed than the 5D Mark 3 or 6D.  It doesn't make any sense other than the fact they have higher resolutions and thus longer readout times, which ML also seems to confirm.

Comment: @AJHenderson moore's law.
Digital Cameras are computers. Computing power increases or cost decreases.
You can move can a given number of bits faster per $ these days then when a 5d3 or a 6d came out.

a 7d2 is a new generation. a 5d2 and 6d are old generation.
7d2 also has better AF and other features than a 5d3 ir 6d.

time and specs both move on.

sensor read out is not the problem at the moment.
video reads the whole sensor then data is thrown away (pixel binning).
The problem is card write speed. That's why we have a buffer. To allow us to capture data fast for a period of time.

Comment: @JasonTan - Yes, newer tech also makes it faster, but APS-c cameras out at the time the 5D Mark iii came out still had faster burst speeds despite the 5D Mark iii being a newer camera.  The 5D Mark iii has the same AF system as the 7D Mark ii, though the 7D does have more cross types, but no word yet on how they perform on a smaller mount size (PDAF is dependent on distance apart too.)  For video, the entire sensor generally isn't read.  Also, memory card speed CAN'T impact the burst speed, only the burst quantity.  You could argue it is the cache speed potentially, but not SD/CF speed.

Comment: (Note, they do bin, but they bin in hardware and often don't read some lines at all for speed.)  This readout speed limitation is also why you get the jello effect of rolling shutter in video.  It would be even more compounded during full frames if not for the shutter actuation in between.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but don't they express the burst rate as bps instead of fps? If yes, then that makes the distinction easy.

Comment: @ferdy - I have never heard the term bps.  Doesn't mean someone might not use it somewhere, but I've never heard it before.

Comment: @AJHenderson Sorry, it turns out that this is a thing in the dutch language only (bps = beelden per seconde = images per second), whilst we do use the english FPS for video. Hence my confusion.

Comment: @AJHenderson actually the card speed does effect the burst speed.
When the buffer is full the camera will only shoot as fast as images can be written to the card.
So the card speed has an effect on burst speed once the buffer is full which might be a few seconds or a minute or more depending on the camera model.

Comment: @jasontan if you want to talk about the sustainable write rate to the card on buffer exhaustion then sure, but I took the meaning to be the max burst speed, which would be going to cache. If you notice, I did say the card impacts the max burst count potentially as it may be possible for the cache to be emptying at the same time it is filling on some cameras, but the memory card speed has zero impact on burst speed until you are out of cache, which I think we agree on.

Comment: @AJHenderson Yes I think most people want the camera to shoot bursts as long as it can without damaging itself, not as long as the buffer holds out.
Hence the bottleneck is the buffer to card as Michael Clark stated and the buffer speed is impacted by card write performance.
As is the cameras ability to recover from a full buffer.

Glad we agree that the memory card does have an effect on burst speed. ;-)

Comment: @JasonTan that's an interesting point about what you think people would expect as the burst speed. It is not what I expect, nor what the manufacturers list as the "burst speed", but it is probably worth making a distinction between "maximum burst speed" and "sustainable burst speed".  Too bad I can't edit the comment for clarity since it wasn't actually in my answer. :(

Answer (score 1):

Both.

It is of no importance for the genre of still photography, but it is or may be when you use "still" just to distinguish between photography and filming. The fps rate is of vast importance for some (or most?) sport photographers.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate why it is not important to still photography but important in sports photography. Sports photography is a form of still photography, correct?

Comment: The word still in the context of photography is ambigous. You may understand it to separate the photography of single photographs from filming - which is technically a long serios of individual photos with some reasonalbe fps rate. 
So for videos some rather high fps rate is a matter of quality until the fps rate reaches a level from which any higher fps rate does not bring any further improvement while watching the video. (High speed videography is different though) 

I understand still as still photography. Something like http://fc-foto.de/27034628 
(cont. in next comment)

Comment: For these stills the fps rate of the camera does not matter at all. I'd be happy with a fps rate of 1 or even lower. As a matter of fact, the reloading-time of the flash light acutally force me to less than 1 frame per second. So something well above 20 fps is probably ok and resonable up to 40 fps or so for regular videos (I am not a filmer, to be frank) 

Some or most sport photographers like to shoot series of individual photos (not videos) of a scene and choose later the best catch they made. For them a body with 6 or more fps (full size high quality photos) is much better than 3 fps.